# Android: Rendering views (text and image) in a rich banner creating app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I am working on a banner creating app where the user can create custom banners for any purpose. The banner will have text, icons, background, etc. The app needs to provide features such as

1. **Text Editing** which includes simple effects like bold, italics, underline, font changes etc. But also more advanced effects
   such as envelope distortion, curving, outline etc. Moreover in the
   future, there may be more such effects that may need to be added.
2. **Background editing** by adding an existing image or creating a background with available options in the app

Think of it as slides in power point where user can add their own text and format it plus have backgrounds. There need to be a lot of customization

I need to decide what tools to use to develop this. The main issue is how to render texts dynamically. The options I have been thinking of are

1. Using TextViews/EditTexts and other top-level view classes
2. Using CustomViews i.e Canvas
3. Using a more advanced and lower-level approach such as an
   ImageProcessing library to render text or even something along the
   lines of 3D graphic rendering.

I need to make a choice that isn't incompatible to support future effects that may be needed. I am pretty sure TextViews/EditTexts etc won't be the solution here. I am not sure how powerful the Canvas class is and whether it is possible to create such an app by just using CustomViews.

Coming to ImageProcessing or 3D graphics, it may be used to have much more control over the effects by using PixelShading/Transformations etc but it comes with its drawbacks. i.e low level of abstraction and higher development time possibly.

Can some more experienced folks give some insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Image Processing and for different themes use lotte-Animations.